# Chaining react hooks using uniswap style template

Tags: react.js, typescript, solidity

I'm trying to chain react hooks together.  I need to do the following

1. Obtain the Balance of NFT's a user has
2. Enumerate the balance of nft's and generate index arguments to call the RPC to get the tokenId
3. Some form of validation or error handling

This is my code:

```
export default function useAccessPassOwnerNFTs(): { data: BigNumber[]; loading: boolean } {
const { account } = useWeb3React()
const accessPass = useAccessPass();
const accountArgument = useMemo(() => [account || ''], [account])
const accessPassBalance = useSingleCallResult(accessPass, 'balanceOf', accountArgument)

const balanceArgs: string[][] = useMemo(
    () =>
      accessPassBalance && account && !accessPassBalance.loading && accessPassBalance.result?.[0] !== undefined
        ? Array.from(Array(accessPassBalance.result?.[0].toNumber())).map((v, i) => [account, i.toString()])
        : [],
    [accessPassBalance, accountArgument]
  )

const ownerTokenResults = useSingleContractMultipleData(accessPass, 'tokenOfOwnerByIndex', balanceArgs)

return useMemo(() => {
    const ownerTokencalldata = [...ownerTokenResults] 

    if(accessPassBalance.loading) {
        return { data: [], loading: true }
    } else if (!accessPassBalance.result?.[0]) {
        return { data: [], loading: false }
    }

    if (accessPassBalance.loading || ownerTokencalldata.some((p) => p.loading)) {
        return { data: [], loading: true }
    }
  
    return {
      data: ownerTokencalldata.map((ownerTokenResult, i) => {
        return ownerTokenResult?.result?.[0]
      }),
      loading: false,
    }
}, [ownerTokenResults, accessPassBalance]);
```

}

I'm not sure if its optimal, ugly or even valid.